# mui material and icon named export throw Module not found error in react application

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-icons

I am using mui  and when using named export, it gives error of module not found issue.

followed this [mui blog](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-two-use-a-babel-plugin) and use babel-plugin approach but error still remian same.

#### package.json

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.14",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.14",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.10.6",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.14.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.38.0",
    "react-loadingmask": "^4.0.6",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
```

#### .babelrc.js

```js
const plugins = [
  [
    'babel-plugin-import',
    {
      libraryName: '@mui/material',
      libraryDirectory: '',
      camel2DashComponentName: false,
    },
    'core',
  ],
  [
    'babel-plugin-import',
    {
      libraryName: '@mui/icons-material',
      libraryDirectory: '',
      camel2DashComponentName: false,
    },
    'icons',
  ],
];

module.exports = { plugins };
```

#### config-overrides.js

```js
/* config-overrides.js */
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/rules-of-hooks */
const { useBabelRc, override } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(useBabelRc());
```

#### src/component/AppBarMain.jsx

here how it has been written as below

```
import { AccountCircle, AddCommentIcon, MailIcon, MenuIcon, MoreIcon, SearchIcon } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { alpha, AppBar, Badge, Box, Button, IconButton, InputBase, Menu, MenuItem, Toolbar, Typography } from '@mui/material';
```

and it gives errors

[image: mui import issue]

what is wrong here, Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `npm i`? Though the imports are in your package.json file, you may not have installed them.